# Retrieve a value from a hash in a hash in an array in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the value of `zap` in a hash that looks like:

```rb
hash = {
         :foo => 1,
         :bar => [{
           :baz => 2,
           :zot => {
             :zap => 3
           }
         }]
       }
```

`hash.dig` breaks as soon as it gets to the array.

If it's important, this is a step in an `if/elsif/else` statement checking for different error messages. (i.e. `elsif zap == 3`)

Comment: Can you post your code which attempts to retrieve the value, and the error you receive. It will help people answer your question if they have a starting point

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
hash[:bar].first.dig(:zot, :zap)
```

Comment: Hey there, `hash.dig(:bar, 0, :zot, :zap)` - also will work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are incorrect, and `dig` in fact works on any object with a `dig` method. Dig is defined both for [arrays](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig). Also, if I define a dig method on a custom object:

```rb
o = Object.new

def o.dig(*args)
  puts args.inspect
  return :result
end
```

then when called like so:

```rb
{custom_object: o}.dig(:custom_object,1,2,3)
#-> output: [1,2,3]
#=> :result
```

you can see that dig gets called on `o` with the remaining arguments (`[1,2,3]`) and returns whatever the custom dig method returns.

What you may have missed is that for arrays, you need to use a numeric index, or dig raises a type error when it gets called on the array. So `hash.dig(:bar, 0, :zot, :zap)` is what you probably want. (credit to Alex for beating me to the punch).